# Spring Boot - webservice: Connection Refused

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to implement spring boot webservice application as given in spring docs :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

Build was successful, request and response java files was created and , but when executed spring-boot:run , it gives

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at hello.WeatherClient.getCityForecastByZip(WeatherClient.java:30)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:20)
```

But the URL is accessible via web browser in eclipse. Kindly help me solve this issue

Comment: Are you in a corporate network where you access internet through a corporate proxy ? Do you have a proxy setting that you set to access the internet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web Service URL you are trying to call may be not reachable or it gets timeout. Ensure the web Service URL path is correct and is listening. also verify the timeout duration set and the time taken from your request.

`PS. Also check if there is some firewall issue at Server side.`

For firewall issue, you might need to provide proxy details(proxyHost and proxyPort) In client code.

EDIT:

I am not able to find appropriate blog or something which explains it better. but found one question on stackoverflow which has similar answer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543414/spring-mvc-giving-connection-refused-when-connecting-to-rest-service-with-https)

Comment: Can you please share me some link , where i can check and correct my proxy settings?

Comment: have you verified the webservice url and port is it fine ?

Comment: Yeah its fine . i have added

Comment: ` System.setProperty("proxyHost", "yourproxy.server.com");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8080");'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your tests declared with same `@SpringBootTest` annotation parameters.
I had same issue because of different parameters in two tests. Problem gone when I made all annotations same:
 `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)`)