# Rest java.net.ConnectException : while connecting two SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, webservice-client

When i tried to consume from my first springboot application to another via RestTemplate getting below error from postman

Request URI:http://localhost:8083/template/getprodgsspringboot

```
"timestamp": "2019-03-15T10:02:39.168+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "I/O error on GET request for \"http://localhost:8080/products\": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect",
"path": "/template/getprodgsspringboot"
```

First spring boot Application : Rest controller

```
@RequestMapping("/template/getprodgsspringboot")
public String getProductList() {
    HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> http=new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    return resttemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/products",HttpMethod.GET,http,String.class).getBody();
}
```

Second Spring boot Application :Rest controller

```
//GET Method of rest webservice
@RequestMapping("/products")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getMethod(){
    System.out.println("My GET http method");
    retu
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40106981/7924858 follow this link might help you

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below resttemplate and give a try. It should work

ResponseEntity result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/products", HttpMethod.GET, http, String.class);